# Changing Internet Explorer settings programmatically

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer, winapi

In Internet Explorer, **Internet Options -> Advanced** we have Multiple **check-box** for settings.

I want to programmatically manage all of them.

I looked at Internet Explorer API but doesn't find much.

**Edit**

I want specifically Uncheck these two check boxes

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: I would imagine all those settings are managed via Registry.

Comment: yeah but is there any option to manage them prgrammatically?

Comment: Which settings specifically are you interested in? There are different interfaces depending on the setting. For example IInternetSecurityManager controls some of them.

Comment: You use `CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled`. One of them is `FEATURE_WARN_ON_SEC_CERT_REV_FAILED`. I didn't bother to look up the other one. You can look it up yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You are more than likely going to need to change the registry settings to programmatically alter those fields. You can start poking around this key:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Comment: Do you have any reference or know any Internet Explorere API?

Comment: This is only to set **Security Zone setting** only, Please have a look on edit part now.

Comment: What do you want to do with this code, before I tell you how to do it?

Comment: This is pre-requisite for one of application by a GDS (Amadeus) which only works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manipulate the Registry keys as most of those settings are very likely to stored in the Registry.

To programmatically access the Registry, you can use the [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, for example.